# In two ListViews, how to set item source of second from collection of selected item of the first?

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I have two ListViews in a MAUI page.

This is the two list views:

```
    <ListView x:Name="lvAplicaciones" Background="red"
              SeparatorVisibility="Default"
              SeparatorColor="AliceBlue"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Aplicaciones}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding AplicacionesSelectedItem}"
              HeightRequest="50"
              HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Nombre}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>


    <ListView x:Name="lvAcciones" Background="Yellow"
              SeparatorVisibility="Default"
              SeparatorColor="AliceBlue"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source=lvAplicaciones, Path=SelectedItem.Acciones}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding AccionesSelectedItem}"
              HeightRequest="50"
              HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Nombre}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

This is the classes that are the source of the list views:

```
public class Aplicacion
{
    #region constructures
    public Aplicacion(string paramStrNombre)
    {
        _nombre = paramStrNombre;
    }

    public Aplicacion(string paramStrNombre, IEnumerable<Accion> paramIeAcciones) : this(paramStrNombre)
    {
        _acciones.AddRange(paramIeAcciones);
    }
    #endregion constructores





    #region Nombre: propiedades
    private readonly string _nombre;
    public string Nombre => _nombre;
    #endregion Nombre: propiedades





    #region Acciones: propiedades
    private readonly List<Accion> _acciones = new List<Accion>();
    public List<Accion> Acciones => _acciones;
    #endregion Acciones: propiedades

    #region Acciones: métodos
    public List<Accion> GetAcciones()
    {
        return Acciones.ToList();
    }
    #endregion Acciones: métodos
}





public class Accion
{
    //NOTA: de la acción al cliente solo le intersa el nombre y la descripción. El comando y los parámetros no, es
    //solo a nivel del servidor.
    #region constructures
    public Accion(string paramStrNombre, string paramStrDescripcion)
    {
        _nombre = paramStrNombre;
        _descripcion = paramStrDescripcion;
    }
    #endregion constructores





    private readonly string _nombre;
    public string Nombre => _nombre;



    private readonly string _descripcion;
    public string Descripcion => _descripcion;
}
```

The first listview shows the items that I expected, they are created in the view model. But when I select an item in this list view, the second list view doesn't show the items in the colecction Acciones of the selected Aplicacion.

Thanks.

Comment: According to the official document about the [relative binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings) and the [multibinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/multibinding), there is no any using way like `Path=SelectedItem.Acciones` .

Comment: Then I guess the option it is binding to the SelectedItem of Aplicaciones in the view model and populate collection of Action.

Comment: You can try to create a new variable in your viewmodel and bind it to the second listview.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Yes, it is the solution that I am using. Thank you so much.